# Resume Supported ONE Time file downloading

Tags: php, apache

I'm using a code which uses range headers to make a resume supported file download.
I want to let a user download a specific file just 1 time. Do anybody have any solution?

I think i should find out that the download has been finished or not. Is there any way to do that with PHP? ( or any help from apache )

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to check whether file downloaded or not. But you can try to guess it based on specific feauteres.

If you sending files with php script, you can write how many bytes you send to user.

And you can add some checkpoints in file (numered bytes), if you send them all and sent size more 125% of real file size, you guess that file recieved.

Comment: Than you for your answer. But how accurate is 125%? Doesn't it depend on the speed of the user?

Comment: It depends on user's network connection quality. Sometimes when you send data via http, it isn't recieved by user. 125% is an experimental value.

Comment: Wont lost packets be sent by TCP? IF so we don't need to manage that. Am i right? (So these wont be counted as sent bytes, do they?)

Comment: You can't be sure is packet written by php delivered to recipient. If the client unexpectedly closes connection some packets written by php (that counts sent packets) may be not recieved.